# How to make python scripts pipe-able both in bash and within python

Tags: python, pipeline, python-multithreading

**Summary**: I'd like to write python scripts that act like bash scripts on the command line, but then I'd also like to pipe them together easily in python. Where I'm having trouble is the glue to make the latter happen.

So imagine I wrote two scripts, `script1.py` and `script2.py` and I can pipe them together like so:

```
echo input_string | ./script1.py -a -b | ./script2.py -c -d
```

**How do I get this behavior from within another python file?**
Here's the way I know, but I don't like:

```
arg_string_1 = convert_to_args(param_1, param_2)
arg_string_2 = convert_to_args(param_3, param_4)
output_string = subprocess.check_output("echo " + input_string + " | ./script1.py " + arg_string_1 + " | ./script2.py " + arg_string_2)
```

If I didn't want to take advantage of multithreading, I could do something like this (?):

```
input1  = StringIO(input_string)
output1 = StringIO()
script1.main(param_1, param_2, input1, output1)
input2  = StringIO(output1.get_value())
output2 = StringIO()
script2.main(param_3, param_4, input2, output2)
```

---

Here's the approach I was trying, but I got stuck at writing the glue. I'd appreciate either learning how to finish my approach below, or suggestions for a better design/approach!

My approach: I wrote `script1.py` and `script2.py` to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

... # import sys and define "parse_args"

def main(param_1, param_2, input, output):
   for line in input:
     ...
     print(stuff, file=output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  parameter_1, parameter_2 = parse_args(sys.argv)
  main(parameter_1, parameter_2, sys.stdin, sys.stdout)
```

Then I wanted to write something like this, but don't know how to finish:

```
pipe_out, pipe_in = ????
output = StringIO()
thread_1 = Thread(target=script1.main, args=(param_1, param_2, StreamIO(input_string), pipe_out))
thread_2 = Thread(target=script2.main, args=(param_3, param_4, pipe_in, output)
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()
output_str = output.get_value()
```

Answer (score 2):

For the "pipe in", uses `sys.stdin` with the `readlines()` method.  (Using method `read()` would read one character at a time.)

For passing information from one thread to another, you can use `Queue`.  You must define one way to signal the end of data.  In my example, since all data passed between threads are `str`, I simply use a `None` object to signal the end of data (since it cannot appear in the transmitted data).

One could also use more threads, or use different functions in threads.

I did not include the `sys.argv`in my example to keep it simple.  Modifying it to get parameters (`parameter1`, ...) should be easy.

```
import sys
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import fileinput

def stdin_to_queue( output_queue ):
  for inp_line in sys.stdin.readlines():     # input one line at at time                                                
    output_queue.put( inp_line, True, None )  # blocking, no timeout
  output_queue.put( None, True, None )    # signal the end of data                                                  


def main1(input_queue, output_queue, arg1, arg2):
  do_loop = True
  while do_loop:
    inp_data = input_queue.get(True)
    if inp_data is None:
      do_loop = False
      output_queue.put( None, True, None )  # signal end of data                                                    
    else:
      out_data = arg1 + inp_data.strip('\r\n').upper() + arg2 #  or whatever transformation...                                    
      output_queue.put( out_data, True, None )

def queue_to_stdout(input_queue):
  do_loop = True
  while do_loop:
    inp_data = input_queue.get(True)
    if inp_data is None:
      do_loop = False
    else:
      sys.stdout.write( inp_data )


def main():
  q12 = Queue()
  q23 = Queue()
  q34 = Queue()
  t1 = Thread(target=stdin_to_queue, args=(q12,) )
  t2 = Thread(target=main1, args=(q12,q23,'(',')') )
  t3 = Thread(target=main1, args=(q23,q34,'[',']') )
  t4 = Thread(target=queue_to_stdout, args=(q34,))
  t1.start()
  t2.start()
  t3.start()
  t4.start()


main()
```

Finally, I tested this program (python2) with a text file.

```
head sometextfile.txt | python script.py
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems good, just a lot of code. I was hoping there might be something more concise. But if the performance is good, it might be worth it.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to reduce it.  For example, you could read directly from a file and write directly to a file within the same thread.  I purposefully separated a lot of thing to illustrate many things individually.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the return value to stdout depending on whether the script is being run from the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

# Example function
def main(input):
    # Do something with input producing stuff
    ...
    return multipipe(stuff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def multipipe(data):
        print(data)

    input = parse_args(sys.argv)
    main(input)
else:
    def multipipe(data):
        return data
```

Each other script will have the same two definitions of `multipipe`. Now, use `multipipe` for output.

If you call all the scripts together from the command line `$ ./scrip1.py | ./scrip2.py`, each will have `__name__ == '__main__'` and so `multipipe` will print it all to stdout to be read as an argument by the next script (and return `None`, so each function returns `None`, but you're not looking at the return values anyway in this case).

If you call them within some other python script, each function will return whatever you passed to `multipipe`.

Effectively, you can use your existing functions, just replace `print(stuff, file=output)` with `return multipipe(stuff)`. Nice and simple.

To use it with multithreading or multiprocessing, set the functions up so that each function returns a single thing, and plug them into a simple function that adds data to a multithreading queue. For an example of such a queueing system, see [the sample at the bottom of the Queue docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue). With that example, just make sure that each step in the pipeline puts `None` (or other sentinel value of your choice - I like `...` for that since it's extremely rare that you'd pass the `Ellipsis` object for any reason other than as a marker for its singleton-ness) in the queue to the next one to signify done-ness.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple solution using the standard `Popen` class.

Here's an example:

```
#this is the master python program
import subprocess
import sys
import os

#note the use of stdin and stdout arguments here
process1 = subprocess.Popen(['./script1.py'], stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process2 = subprocess.Popen(['./script2.py'], stdin=process1.stdout)

process1.wait()
process2.wait()
```

the two scripts are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#script1.py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.strip().upper())
```

Here's the second one

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#script2.py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print("<{}>".format(line.strip()))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely better than my solution. It does still leave open how to deal with parameters. This solution seems to require taking a parameter object, converting it into a string, passing it through Popen, and then process1 parses the string and re-creates the object. It would be nice to just directly pass objects through.

Comment: @usul parameters are no problem, just put `['./script1.py', 'param1', 'param2']` in the call to Popen instead of just `['./script1.py']`

Comment: Hi @Yoav, yes this works well if the parameters are already strings. But not as nice if they are lists or more complicated objects. For example if I have a datetime object, I have to first convert it to a string, then pass it in, then script1.py has to parse it into a datetime object again.

Comment: @usul, well - command line arguments are always strings - there is no escaping that. If you want to communicate Python objects between Python processes - there are better solutions than passing them as a string on a command line. From the original question however, I gathered that you wanted to know how to do piping - which is what I addressed.

If you know that your are running python processes, you can pipe between them Pickled objects for example.

Comment: yes, the problem is I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too. I want to support both calling scripts from the command line where arguments are strings, and calling them from python where arguments are processes, and I want to pipe information through in both cases.